# is there anyone who can help to solve this?

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

[Getting this error even though Everything is alright in Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa9T3.png)

Edited Environment Variables, and reinstalled node.js many times, Is there any NPM Problem?

even the Environment variables' path is perfect...

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Directory not empty. It's trying to delete directories and their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Try removing cache and then install

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i
npm i appium
```

2 try this

```
npm uninstall -g appium
npm i -g appium
```

3 try to remove the mentioned directory and then install

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\AAV\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\build\lib\basedriver\commands"
npm i
npm i appium
```

If still error is not solved copy the error given and paste it here. Moreover you can share logs from this path `C:\Users\AAV\AppData\Local\npm-cach&logs\2024-02-07T10_04_18_023Z-debug-0.1og`

Comment: done this many times